# Can I combine the address bar and the Google search bar in Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, safari-extensions

The only reason I am using Chrome over Safari is the cool feature Chrome has namely the address bar acts as the search bar as well. Is there a way I can enable this feature in safari as well?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want the Google-suggestions to appear, too, I think you might be looking for the free (SIMBL) plug-in [Keywurl](http://alexstaubo.github.com/keywurl/).

Answer (score 0):

[SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) also offers this functionality, using the same SIMBL hack as Keywurl.

On the face of it, the main advantage of Keywurl over SafariStand seems to be its backward compatibility with Sogudi extensions, which is why I would recommend following Asmus' recommendation and use Keywurl.

On the more general point of browser selection, I switched from Safari to Google Chrome for the alleged speed improvement, [smarter tab behaviour](http://www.theinvisibl.com/2009/12/08/chrometabs/) and search-in-addressbar functionalities. The two last functionalities seem more robust in Chrome than Safari to me (not sure about speed).