# Where is the SafariStand menu/preferences?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Inspired by this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/safari-address-bar-google-search#answer-9955) I installed [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) (after installing [SIMBAL](http://culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php)) (following instrtuctions in the read me file

> **How To Install**
>   - Install SIMBL 0.9.5 or later http://culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php
>   - Quit Safari.
>   - move "SafariStand.bundle" into your SIMBL plugin folder.
>   - Result path is "/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/SafariStand.bundle".

and also in [this](http://www.pimpmysafari.com/safaristand) website)

Now that the installation is done, I am unable to see the menu/icon of SafariStand There is not much documentation anywhere.

Where/how do I see the SafariStand settings window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the "Stand" menu to appear between the "Window" and "Help" menus in your top menu bar.

Comment: It doesn't. Let me try re installing...

Comment: What happened when you reinstalled? Is everything else up to date?

Comment: (thanks for asking) Reinstallation worked. Looks like I did something wrong when I installed first. Able to see the stand menu.